# Access Context in ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a ContentProvider Class and a DatabaseHelper Class (extends SQLiteOpenHelper).
The ContentProvider instantiates the Helper which needs access to a Context because the constructor requires it:

```
public DBHelper(Context context, AssetFileDescriptor db_asset) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
```

Do you know at least a single way to get the Context from the ContentProvider?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your ContentProvider.onCreate method you can pass the result of getContext() to the DBHelper

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getContext(), db_asset);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I was focused on passing "this" as usual with constructors, didn't get the Idea to try something that trivial :)

Comment: "focused on passing this" - you should pass application context instead of activity context to prevent memory leaks, see [this post](http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html).

Comment: Well, Julian, it's not your fault if there is not much of a consistency in "this", "getActivity()", "getContext()", etc. use.

Answer (score 6):

> Do you know at least a single way to get the Context from the ContentProvider?

[`ContentProvider:getContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#getContext%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

Try this my friend:

```
SampleClass sample = new SampleClass(this.getContext());
```

Where `this` refer to the class that extends the ContentProvider...
And `.getContext()` will get the context of the class that extends the ContentProvider..

Hope this one helps..